# Use multiple checkbox values calculations on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var total = 0;

    function test(item){
        if(item.checked){
           total+= parseInt(item.value);
        }else{
           total-= parseInt(item.value);
        }
        //alert(total);
        document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + " ";
        document.getElementById('Totalcost2').innerHTML = total + " ";
        document.getElementById('Totalcost3').innerHTML = total + " ";
    }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

   <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="10" onClick="test(this,);"  />10<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="20" onClick="test(this,);" />20 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" onClick="test(this,);" />40 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" onClick="test(this,);" />60 <br />

Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="10" onClick="test(this,);"  />10<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="20" onClick="test(this,);" />20 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" onClick="test(this,);" />40 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" onClick="test(this,);" />60 <br />

    Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost2"> </span><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="10" onClick="test(this,);"  />10<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="20" onClick="test(this,);" />20 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" onClick="test(this,);" />40 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" onClick="test(this,);" />60 <br />

    Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost3"> </span><br />
    </html>
```

My question is how to set it to show 3 different sums on the same page without conflicts, about conflicts I mean if I set 3 times the `id="Totalcost"` on the same page it should show them differently but they show the same, i tried to set 3 different id's id=Totalcost, Totalcost2 and Totalcost3 for example but it doesn't work it goes in conflict.

Comment: it doesnt work isn't good question, please post your (broken) code. it should work, though.

Comment: What do you mean by `conflict` and what is your desired output?

Comment: I have 3 tables, I want 3 tables that they shows 3 different sums when they checkbox, because now when they checkbox they shows 3 equal results - example https://ibb.co/m7TPWc

Comment: Maybe the conflict is being caused by the fact that `total` is a shared variable. You may use the same JS code for multiple `Totalcost` fields, but each one must have its own set of values... Try storing them on an Array and controlling which element will be read from there with an index, it should work.

Comment: @DeyanNik then specify the HTML of your table because the above code seems to work as it should

Comment: This is extremely hard to understand. If you have 3 tables, do they each with their own checkboxes? If so, can you please update your code snippet in the question to show the **actual** problem by adding the **actual** HTML and code you have. Your question currently shows perfectly working code but should be demonstrating the issue.

Comment: ID is a unique field even though you can use it more than once in html, it is a no no. When you refer to it using javascript it will change in the first location only (i believe). Use a different id for each Total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, because I'm not sure :

You can't attribute same ID to multiple elements.

You have to do something like this :

```
function test(){
    var checklist = document.getElementById('modulo')
                            .getElementsByClassName('checklist');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < checklist.length ; i++) {

        var checkboxes = checklist[i].querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
            sum = 0;

        for (var j = 0 ; j < checkboxes.length ; j++) {
            if (checkboxes[j].checked) {
                sum += Number(checkboxes[j].value)
            } 
        }

        checklist[i].getElementsByClassName('totalcost')[0].innerHTML = sum + " ";
    }
}

document.getElementById('modulo').addEventListener('change',test,false)
```

And in BODY :

```
<form id="modulo">
    <div class="checklist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="10" />10<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="20" />20 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" />40 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" />60 <br /><br />
        Total Amount : <span class="totalcost"> </span><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="checklist">
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="10" />10<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="20" />20 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" />40 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" />60 <br /><br />
        Total Amount : <span class="totalcost"> </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, because it uses the same `total` variable. Wait I'm improving this :)

Comment: Working for me. Tell me. If you plan to use a lot of `total` variables, maybe you should do differently. Otherwise, add as many `total` variable as needed

Comment: There is a problem, when you uncheck them they result at minus - not at 0 or empty @Loarg Ann

Comment: Can I set them without the attribude name="channelcost"? because my form checkbox are connected with PayPal so I have already name attributes @Loarg

Comment: If you have to keep the `name`, you can add `data` attributes : 
`<input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" data-checklist="1" value="10" onClick="test(this);"  />`. So the variable `a` will be `a = item.getAttribute('data-checklist')`. I see for the minus, I don't know why by now :/

Comment: I tried right now the code it doesnt work when I checkbox hm :/ thanks very much btw @Loarg Ann

Comment: Try this new one. I completly changed the function but it's moooore simple and you can add as many checklists as you want. Just insert each checklist into a `div` with `class="cheklist"` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aYXegv

Comment: Thanks alot, very helpful, thanks very much again @Loarg Ann

Comment: È stato un piacere :)

Comment: Italiano? ehehe come hai fatto a capire che lo ero anch'io, comunque mille grazie ti ringrazio tanto, non sono molto esperto ma cerco di imparare @Loarg Ann

Comment: No, non sono italiana ma l'ho studiato 7 anni e ho riprenduto questo mese per, perche no, andare in italia presto. Neanche sono una esperta ma era divertente aiutarti ^^ Ho capito solo perche è scrito su tuo profile eheh

Comment: Aaaah ahahah giusto mi ero scordato che nel profilo c'erano anche questi dati :D - sei brava con la programmazione, io sono bulgaro ma vivo in italia da 13 anni, da piccolo che ho imparato a lavorare con HTML, PHP, JS ma non sono ancora molto bravo con il Java e il PHP, imparo guardando su internet e a volte se non riesco chiedo, grazie di nuovo per il tempo dedicato @Loarg Ann

Comment: Bulgaro oh! Sono la giustiziera di StackOverflow ahah. Non mi piace quando faccio una domanda e ricevo molti voti negativi, perche nessuno commincia professionale. Sfortunatamente conosco solo il JavaScript a differenza di te. Non esitate a validare mia risposto, è bene per mia reputazione ^^